# How to build the following table (picture below) using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

Here is the table that I'm trying to build. How can it be done with Ti*k*Z?

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Here is the code I'm using. But now I need to remove the outer border (as in the picture above). How to remove the outer border?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{%
square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum size=#1,
      anchor=center,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
    column 1/.style={nodes={fill=lightgray!30}},
    row 1/.style={nodes={fill=lightgray!30}},
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm
}
\matrix[square matrix] (A)
{
         & 0        & 2         & 4         & 6         & 8         & $\cdots$\\ 
0        & 0        & 2         & 4         & 6         & 8         & $\ddots$\\ 
2        & 2        & 4         & 6         & 8         & $\ddots$  &         \\ 
4        & 4        & 6         & 8         & $\ddots$  &           &         \\ 
6        & 6        & 8         & $\ddots$  &           &           &         \\ 
8        & 8        & $\ddots$  &           &           &           &         \\ 
$\vdots$ & $\ddots$ &           &           &           &           &         \\ 
};
\draw (A-1-1.north west)--(A-1-1.south east);
\node[below left=2mm and 2mm of A-1-1.north east] {$k$};
\node[above right=2mm and 2mm of A-1-1.south west] {$j$};
        \node[
            inner sep=-4pt,
            draw=black, 
            very thick,
            dashed,                        
            rounded corners=0.5em, 
            rotate fit=45, 
            fit={(A-3-2) (A-2-3)}] {};
        \node[
            inner sep=-4pt,
            draw=black, 
            very thick,
            dashed,                        
            rounded corners=0.5em, 
            rotate fit=45, 
            fit={(A-4-2) (A-2-4)}] {};            
        \node[
            inner sep=-4pt,
            draw=black, 
            very thick,        
            dashed,            
            rounded corners=0.5em, 
            rotate fit=45, 
            fit={(A-5-2) (A-2-5)}] {};                
        \node[
            inner sep=-4pt,
            draw=black, 
            very thick,
            dashed,                        
            rounded corners=0.5em, 
            rotate fit=45, 
            fit={(A-6-2) (A-2-6)}] {};                
            
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is the result.

[image]

Comment: could you upload your code highlighting what you have tried - data entry is the most tiring part

Comment: The problematic part are those diagonals.

Comment: ...and the top left corner...

Comment: Nothing on that image is hard. The diagonals can be make using the fit library (I think that is the one). The top left is also easy to do by hand.

Comment: @Neves If the diagonal lines and the left corner are the problem, then please show some code without them. I'm sure people can then use this code as a starting point and help you with the diagonal lines and the corner.

Comment: Take a look at the package `nicematrix `

Comment: Try `{fill=none}` instead of `{fill=lightgray!30}` or discard the fill-option entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick hack to remove the outer border: draw a rectangle in your background colour above it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{%
square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum size=#1,
      anchor=center,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
    column 1/.style={nodes={fill=lightgray!30}},
    row 1/.style={nodes={fill=lightgray!30}},
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm
}
\matrix[square matrix] (A)
{
         & 0        & 2         & 4         & 6         & 8         & $\cdots$\\ 
0        & 0        & 2         & 4         & 6         & 8         & $\ddots$\\ 
2        & 2        & 4         & 6         & 8         & $\ddots$  &         \\ 
4        & 4        & 6         & 8         & $\ddots$  &           &         \\ 
6        & 6        & 8         & $\ddots$  &           &           &         \\ 
8        & 8        & $\ddots$  &           &           &           &         \\ 
$\vdots$ & $\ddots$ &           &           &           &           &         \\ 
};
\draw (A-1-1.north west)--(A-1-1.south east);
\node[below left=2mm and 2mm of A-1-1.north east] {$k$};
\node[above right=2mm and 2mm of A-1-1.south west] {$j$};
        \node[
            inner sep=-4pt,
            draw=black, 
            very thick,
            dashed,                        
            rounded corners=0.5em, 
            rotate fit=45, 
            fit={(A-3-2) (A-2-3)}] {};
        \node[
            inner sep=-4pt,
            draw=black, 
            very thick,
            dashed,                        
            rounded corners=0.5em, 
            rotate fit=45, 
            fit={(A-4-2) (A-2-4)}] {};            
        \node[
            inner sep=-4pt,
            draw=black, 
            very thick,        
            dashed,            
            rounded corners=0.5em, 
            rotate fit=45, 
            fit={(A-5-2) (A-2-5)}] {};                
        \node[
            inner sep=-4pt,
            draw=black, 
            very thick,
            dashed,                        
            rounded corners=0.5em, 
            rotate fit=45, 
            fit={(A-6-2) (A-2-6)}] {};                
        \draw[white,ultra thick] (A-1-1.north west)  rectangle (A-7-7.south east);   
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]